# Matplotlib mutli-barchart plots

Tags: python, matplotlib, bar-chart

can someone please post an example for drawing to images on one plot, both of them are barcharts.
Every one should look like this one here : 
http://matplotlib.org/examples/api/barchart_demo.html

The problem with this example, it  doesn't tell how add another chart to it, and if, how to set the configurations of every one of them.

Answer (score 1):

You should use fig=plt.figure() and after that add two subplots ax=fig.add_subplot(2,2,1) and ax2=fig.add_subplot(2,2,2). After that you can do everything with ax and ax2.

A modified example from your reference:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

N = 5
menMeans = (20, 35, 30, 35, 27)
menStd =   (2, 3, 4, 1, 2)

ind = np.arange(N)  # the x locations for the groups
width = 0.35       # the width of the bars

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(2,2,1)
rects1 = ax.bar(ind, menMeans, width, color='r', yerr=menStd)

womenMeans = (25, 32, 34, 20, 25)
womenStd =   (3, 5, 2, 3, 3)
rects2 = ax.bar(ind+width, womenMeans, width, color='y', yerr=womenStd)

# add some text for labels, title and axes ticks
ax.set_ylabel('Scores')
ax.set_title('Scores by group and gender')
ax.set_xticks(ind+width)
ax.set_xticklabels( ('G1', 'G2', 'G3', 'G4', 'G5') )

ax.legend( (rects1[0], rects2[0]), ('Men', 'Women') )

def autolabel(rects):
    # attach some text labels
    for rect in rects:
        height = rect.get_height()
        ax.text(rect.get_x()+rect.get_width()/2., 1.05*height, '%d'%int(height),
                ha='center', va='bottom')

autolabel(rects1)
autolabel(rects2)

ax2 = fig.add_subplot(2,2,2)
rects3 = ax2.bar(ind, menMeans, width, color='r', yerr=menStd)

womenMeans = (20, 32, 34, 20, 25)
womenStd =   (3, 7, 2, 3, 3)
rects4 = ax2.bar(ind+width, womenMeans, width, color='y', yerr=womenStd)

ax2.set_ylabel('Scores_2')
ax2.set_title('Scores by group and gender_2')
ax2.set_xticks(ind+width)
ax2.set_xticklabels( ('G1_2', 'G2_2', 'G3_2', 'G4_2', 'G5_2') )

ax2.legend( (rects1[0], rects2[0]), ('Men_2', 'Women_2') )

def autolabel(rects):
    # attach some text labels
    for rect in rects:
        height = rect.get_height()
        ax2.text(rect.get_x()+rect.get_width()/2., 1.05*height, '%d'%int(height),
                ha='center', va='bottom')

autolabel(rects3)
autolabel(rects4)

plt.show()
```